# Is it good practice to use variables from outer functions?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, coding-style

I try to learn Scala programming language.

Is it good and popular practice to use variables/arguments from outer function in inner function?

For example:

```
def foo(x: Int) = {
     val x2 = 10
     def foo2()
     {
         // is it normal to use x and x2 here?
     }
}
```

Comment: util, you define the variable in the same name inside `foo2`, you have scope to access outer function `foo` variable. Why you need nested function.?

Comment: yes, I know that it is possible but I do not have any experience and I do not know if it is proper coding style.

Comment: That's kind of the entire point of having support for nested functions in a language, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in Scala that's called *closures*. If `x` an `x2` appear free in the scope of `foo2`, you have to close that open term (`foo2`) providing the values for both variables.

You can have access to variables defined outside `foo2` and thus, appearing as free variables in the scope of your inner function. As an example, consider:

```
// some context
val more: Int = 4
def sumMore(x: Int): Int = x + more
```

In the last line, we have `x` which is a bound variable, and `more` which appears as a free variable inside the `sumMore` function.

Any function literal having free variables (like `sumMore`, which depends on the value of `more`) will be an open term because it requires a binding for `more`. The name *closure* arises from the act of closing the open term by providing values to the free variables which appear in the scope of its body.

Let's see what happens if we do not provide a value for `more`:

```
scala> def sumMore(x: Int): Int = x + more
<console>:7: error: not found: value more
       def sumMore(x: Int): Int = x + more
                                      ^
```

What if `more` is in the scope of `sumMore` (defined outside):

```
scala> val more: Int = 4
more: Int = 4

scala> def sumMore(x: Int): Int = x + more
sumMore: (x: Int)Int
```

Comment: It's called a closure not only in Scala :-)

Comment: @Bergi you are right, let's say lambda calculus then :)

Comment: Is there any programming language that uses this concept but doesn't call it "closure"?

Comment: If a language as Javascript uses that term, I'd say no :P